# Disable security warning

Tags: security

How I disable Unverified Publisher security warning box ? I want setup my Ubuntu to start this program after restart automaticaly.

Comment: Can you give us a picture with this warning box in Ubuntu? I am very, very curious how does it look!

Comment: I want give picture but i dont have enough reputation to post images ....

Comment: [I put it on my Google++][1]


  [1]: https://plus.google.com/photos/118220003131152151234/albums/5875735183298730353

Comment: No, that warning does have nothing to do with Unverified Publisher...

Answer (score 1):

I found it ! It is actually a Java setting on the client. If you open IcedTea Web Control panel you can set in Desktop Integration section "Always allow"  option.